# Deploy a dacpack using Azure CloudShell

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, dacpac, azure-cloud-shell

I am new to CloudShell and I want to deploy a SQL database to Azure SQL Server.

Previously (using Windows PowerShell) I have deployed a database using a dacpac file in combination with the Dac framework.

But CloudShell is something on portal & I don't have the Dac framework associated with it. Is there any other way to update/deploy database to Azure SQL Server using CloudShell?

Comment: Don't you want just use publish profile in ms sql server project to deploy to your azure db?

Comment: I don't have a database ready in ms sq server. I have Database Project in visual studio and I got .dacpac file from it. I want to deploy it using Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

I got the workaround for the problem. I have copied Dac framework (130) folder to CloudShell VM which contains SqlPackage.exe file. 
Then I ran the PowerShell script to deploy dacpac & It works!
I am still trying to install SSTD in CLoudShell environment. But for now, I can deploy a database using dacpack.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use PowerShell in the Azure Cloud Shell through the [public preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powershell-comes-to-azure-cloud-shell/). From then, you can import .bacpac files into your Azure SQL Database as explained in this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-import-from-bacpac-powershell). The Dac framework is used internally by the Azure import/export module.

Comment: I need to import **.dacpac** file not **.bacpac**

Comment: The script at the end of this documentation page should pull the trigger https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/deploy-a-data-tier-application

Comment: It requires DAC framework which is not available with CloudShell